# tilling the Hyperbolic plane

Tags: 2d, tesselation

i am trying to tile a hyperbolic plane using the poincaré or Beltrami–Klein disk model. I am doing it recursively and i don't know how to detect overlapping tiles. I think they are causing bugs because of floating point number precision and performance are very bad, so i need to remove them.[image]